# Can I use a micro framework over full-stack framework?

Tags: php, frameworks

I am building a city government website and I'm currently using `Slim Framework`, `Twig templating` and [fluentPDO](https://github.com/lichtner/fluentpdo). I also know how to use full-stacks like `Laravel`, `CodeIgniter`, etc. The website contains news and updates, events, gallery and some more downloadable files. The administrator can login and do these things:

- CRUD of News/Events/Gallery
- Add more admin accounts

So with the details above, would a micro framework like slim framework which is the one I am using suffice it? Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Laravel has a micro framework called Lumen, you can even upgrade later to laravel.

You can find more information here http://lumen.laravel.com/

Answer (score 0):

Any micro-framework would suffice. Though, I wouldn't even use a framework in this case and instead assemble the project purely from various composer libraries and write all the required "connecting tissue" myself.

If you want to explore this approach, you can try reading this: https://github.com/PatrickLouys/no-framework-tutorial ... though it's somewhat incomplete.